# Calculation of CPU Utilization Problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science

> A computer, has an operating system occupying 1GB of memory. The
>   following are the processes with memory sizes and their I/O wait
>   percentages: A(512MB, 50%), B(128MB, 60%), C(64MB, 70%). If the goal
>   is at least 75% CPU utilization, what would be the minimum system
>   memory size requirement? Give examples for how many process A,B, and
>   C's should we run at the same time. (Show your formulas and work
>   clearly, list all your assumptions if you have any)

The formula for CPU utilization is $1-p^{n}$, in which $n$ is number of process running in memory and p is the average percentage of time processes are waiting for I/O.

$$64 = x, 128 = 2x, 512 = 8x$$

$$0.25 = p^n$$

$$0.25 = 0.5*4x * 0.6*2x * 0.7*x$$

$$0.5 = 16x^3 * 0.42$$

For a limited time, I can't go further. Even if I have time, I don't go further. Is my approach is wrong? Is there any simpler way to find it? It is an exam question.

Comment: is the exam ongoing ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee no, it was. I still wonder its answer to learn. Or an approach

Comment: Where'd you get the formula ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=yMDBDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=cpu+utilization+1+p%5En++formul&source=bl&ots=aKxtGnDFxy&sig=ACfU3U1ePStuwVLhI13efutrEaxLP8Ls7Q&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiziKKglb_hAhWj5KYKHQpfBaIQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cpu%20utilization%201%20p%5En%20%20formul&f=false

Answer (score -1):

Given that we have 3 types of processes as follows:

```
Process A : 512 MB with 50% Idle time
Process B : 128 MB with 60% Idle time
Process C : 64  MB with 70% Idle time
```

Now we have each of these as follows:

(Number of each of these processes) = x1 of A, x2 of B and x3 of C

We can calculate CPU Utilisation $\eta$ as follows:

$\eta$ = 1 - 0.5^x1 * 0.6^x2 * 0.7^x3

Now we need to play with x1, x2, x3 such as $\eta$ >= 0.75

(x1,x2,x3) = (1,0,2) results in 0.755 which is as close as you can come to 0.75 with x1,x2,x3 integer. -- (1)

with, (x1,x2,x3) = (1,1,1) utilisation comes out to be 0.79, hence result obtained in statement (1) is the closest you can reach atleast 75% CPU utilisation.

Now, with result obtained in (1), let's calculate system memory size M

M = x1* 512MB + x2* 128MB + x3*64MB + 1024MB (OS)

M = 512+2*64+1024 MB = 1664 MB = 1.625GB

Comment: why are x1 x2 x3 bigger than 0.75? playing values?

Comment: At line number 6, I have explained this, I have assumed that we are having x1 number of processes of type A , x2 of type B and x3 of type C. Playing with x1,x2,x3 means we are required to find an integral solution for equation 1 such that result is close to 0.75